# "Fontconfig warning: ignoring C.UTF-8: not a valid language tag"

Tags: 13.04, fonts

My installation of Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit has stopped detecting file systems and throws

```
Fontconfig warning: ignoring C.UTF-8: not a valid language tag
```

Over and over again. What can I do about this?

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed in Debian, according to [this bug report](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=717423), so the fix will propagate to Ubuntu.